# Артикль «а», не «an»(,) в английском языке

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая?

`1. Мы чаще всего используем артикль «а», не «an»(,) в английском языке.`

`2. Мы чаще всего используем артикль «а», а не «an»(,) в английском языке.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Мы чаще всего используем артикль «а», **не «an»**, в английском языке* (добавочное пояснение).
2. *Мы чаще всего используем артикль **«а», а не «an»** в английском языке* (однородные отношения).

Comment: Лучше еще добавить про второе предложение возможность второй запятой ввиду пояснительного союза _а_. А почему вопрос в виде фотокарточки, а не текста?

Comment: Про фото не поняла, а вот есть ли у нас пояснительный союз А? Вроде бы это противительный союз.  Можете указать источник, где его так называют?

Answer (score 1):

Первое предлагаю оформить так:

***Мы чаще всего используем артикль «а» — не «an»(!) — в английском языке***.

*Не «an»* лучше выделить тире, как вставную конструкцию. Можно воскл. знак либо ставить, либо нет.

Второе можно и так и так:

***Мы чаще всего используем артикль «а», а не «an» в английском языке*** — союз разделяет однородные члены;

***Мы чаще всего используем артикль «а», а не «an», в английском языке*** — **пояснение**, которое присоединяется пояснительным союзом «а».